# Explode a dataframe into a range of another dataframe

Tags: python, python-polars

I have some data in 2 dataframes that look like:

```py
import polars as pl

data = {"channel": [0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1], "time": [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7]}
time_df = pl.DataFrame(data)

data = {
    "time": [10.0, 10.5],
    "event_table": [["start_1", "stop_1", "start_2", "stop_2"], ["start_3"]],
}
events_df = pl.DataFrame(data)
```

where `channel` 0 in the `time_df` means that a new "event table" start here. I want to explode each row of the `event_table` starting at the channels 0 in the `event_df` and have a result like:

```py
data = {
    "channel": [1, 2, 1, 2, 1],
    "time": [0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.7],
    "event": ["start_1", "stop_1", "start_2", "stop_2", "start_3"],
}
result_df = pl.DataFrame(data)
```

What I am currently doing is to remove all channel 0 from the first dataframe, explode the second data frame, and use `hstack` to combine both dataframes. This works OK if my data is perfect.

In reality, the event table can have more (or less) events. In these cases I want to "truncate" the explosion (or fill with nulls) e.g.

```py
import polars as pl

data = {"channel": [0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1], "time": [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7]}
time_df = pl.DataFrame(data)

data = {
    "time": [10.0, 10.5],
    "event_table": [["start_1", "stop_1", "start_2"], ["start_3", "stop_3"]],
}
events_df = pl.DataFrame(data)

data = {
    "channel": [1, 2, 1, 2, 1],
    "time": [0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.7],
    "event": ["start_1", "stop_1", "start_2", None, "start_3"],
}
result_df = pl.DataFrame(data)
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I'm overcomplicating things here but:

The initial approach that comes to mind is to number the events so they align with the row index from the channels.

```py
shape: (2, 2)
┌──────────────────────────────────┬───────┐
│ event_table                      ┆ index │
│ ---                              ┆ ---   │
│ list[str]                        ┆ u32   │
╞══════════════════════════════════╪═══════╡ 
│ ["start_1", "stop_1", "start_2"] ┆ 0     │ # [1, 2, 3]
│ ["start_3", "stop_3"]            ┆ 5     │ # [6, 7]
└──────────────────────────────────┴───────┘
```

#### 1. Run-length encoding

We find the start index and run-length of each channel 0:

```py
rle_df = (
   time_df
    .with_row_index("start")
    .filter(channel = 0)
    .select(
       "start",
       len = pl.col("start").diff().shift(-1) - 1 
    )
    .with_row_index()
)
```

```py
shape: (2, 3)
┌───────┬───────┬──────┐
│ index ┆ start ┆ len  │
│ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---  │
│ u32   ┆ u32   ┆ i64  │
╞═══════╪═══════╪══════╡
│ 0     ┆ 0     ┆ 4    │
│ 1     ┆ 5     ┆ null │
└───────┴───────┴──────┘
```

If `len < event_len` we want to use that as the new length.

#### 2. Truncate

We `join` the run-lengths to `events_df` and use

- [`.min_horizontal()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.min_horizontal.html#polars-min-horizontal) to give use the *"least"* length
- truncate with [`.list.head()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.list.head.html#polars.Expr.list.head)

```py
events_with_index = (
   events_df
    .with_row_index()
    .join(rle_df, on="index", how="left")
    .select(
       pl.col("event_table").list.head(
          pl.min_horizontal(pl.col("len"), pl.col("event_table").list.len())
       ),
       index = pl.col("start")
    )
    .explode("event_table")
    .with_columns(
       pl.col("index") + pl.col("index").cum_count().over("index")
    )
)
```

After the `.explode()` we have:

```py
┌─────────────┬───────┐
│ event_table ┆ index │
│ ---         ┆ ---   │
│ str         ┆ u32   │
╞═════════════╪═══════╡
│ start_1     ┆ 0     │
│ stop_1      ┆ 0     │
│ start_2     ┆ 0     │
│ start_3     ┆ 5     │
│ stop_3      ┆ 5     │
└─────────────┴───────┘
```

The `.cum_count()` addition then gives us:

```py
shape: (5, 2)
┌─────────────┬───────┐
│ event_table ┆ index │
│ ---         ┆ ---   │
│ str         ┆ u32   │
╞═════════════╪═══════╡
│ start_1     ┆ 1     │ # index of 1st channel 0 (plus 1)
│ stop_1      ┆ 2     │
│ start_2     ┆ 3     │
│ start_3     ┆ 6     │ # index of 2nd channel 0 (plus 1)
│ stop_3      ┆ 7     │
└─────────────┴───────┘
```

#### 3. Join

With the indexes aligned, we can `join` and filter out the channel 0 rows.

- A left-join gives us the *"fill with nulls"* behaviour.

```py
(time_df
  .with_row_index()
  .join(
     events_with_index,
     on = "index",
     how = "left"
  )     
  .filter(pl.col("channel") != 0)
)
```

```py
shape: (5, 4)
┌───────┬─────────┬──────┬─────────────┐
│ index ┆ channel ┆ time ┆ event_table │
│ ---   ┆ ---     ┆ ---  ┆ ---         │
│ u32   ┆ i64     ┆ f64  ┆ str         │
╞═══════╪═════════╪══════╪═════════════╡
│ 1     ┆ 1       ┆ 0.2  ┆ start_1     │
│ 2     ┆ 2       ┆ 0.3  ┆ stop_1      │
│ 3     ┆ 1       ┆ 0.4  ┆ start_2     │
│ 4     ┆ 2       ┆ 0.5  ┆ null        │
│ 6     ┆ 1       ┆ 0.7  ┆ start_3     │
└───────┴─────────┴──────┴─────────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very informative. After some testing, this only truncates correctly the last `event_table`. If I add 2 or more events to the first list, the indices start to overlap with the ones in the next list, hence they also show up in the final df.

Comment: To properly truncate all lists I added: an extra `other_index=pl.col("index").shift(-1)` that is the upper bound, and then `clip` the addition of `index` and `cum_count` to that `other_index` column. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Ah interesting, can you show me the exact `event_table` that fails? (Just so I can understand what I missed)